# if $f: (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ is a strictly decreasing then $f \circ f$ is decreasing?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic

I need to find the truth value of the statement "for each strictly decreasing function $f :(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$,the composition function function $f\circ f$ is decreasing".
Can I find a function to disprove this statement? Can I use the function $f :(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$, where $f(x)=\dfrac1x$?

Comment: Your single counterexample is all you need. @Leg 's answer below says even more.

Answer (score 6):

Since $f$ is strictly decreasing on $(0,\infty)$, we have that for any $x_1,x_2 \in (0,\infty)$ such that $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$, which in turn means that $f(f(x_1)) < f(f(x_2))$. Hence, in fact $f \circ f$ is strictly increasing.